# Pretty permalinks (again)

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to enable pretty permalinks in my WordPress site. But every time I try to change to any permalink option besides default the links to the posts go to 404. If I change it back, it works ok.

I'm using WP 4.2.4 with Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu Server 14.04. Things I've done:

- I have `mod_rewrite` enabled in Apache.
- I have Options `+FollowSymLinks` and `AllowOverride All` and `RewriteEngine On` in the config file of my Apache server.
- I have given write permission for `.htaccess` in the root of my site and it's being created fine. I know this because I deleted, changed the permalink option and it was recreated.
- I tryied to put `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` in `.htacess`
- This is a VPS. I have root access.
- I do have other sites configured, but I have tried to remove all other sites from sites-enabled folder and leave only this one and the problem persisted.
- It's a new WP installation, I don't have any plug-ins installed.

I've been through many pages, tutorials and question on this issue with no luck.
Any idea on what would be the problem?

**Edit**

apachectl -M results:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

uname -a results:

```
Linux myhost 2.6.32-042stab108.8 #1 SMP Wed Jul 22 17:23:23 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release -a results:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

VPS specs:

CPU:4.8Ghz  RAM:2Gb  Disk:40Gb  Bandwidth:2000Gb

**Edit 2**

I also found this plug-in:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-post-permalinks/

runned all 3 options (post, page, attachment), same thing.

My blog is here if anyone wants to take a look:
http://www.ideiassobrecodigo.com.br/

**Edit 3** (Answering to @WisdmLabs)

When I started to look for this problem I had the following structure in my site:

symbolic link www in /var pointing to /opt/company
5 symbolic links inside /opt/company pointing to /opt/
among them my site. So to clarify:

```
|-opt
|  |-site1
|  |-site2
|  |-ideiassobrecodigo <---------------------------|
|  |-company <---------------<---------------------|---
|     |-site1 <SL-site1>                           ^  | 
|     |-site2 <SL-site2>                           |  |
|     |-ideiassobrecodigo <SL-ideiassobrecodigo> ->|  |
|     |-site4 <SL-site4>                              ^
|     |-site5 <SL-site5>                              |
|  |-site4                                            |
   |-site5                                            |
|-var                                                 |
   |-www <SL-company> -------->-----------------------|
```

(SL means symbolic link)
So I had the following virtualhost configuration for each site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ideiassobrecodigo
        ServerName www.ideiassobrecodigo.com.br
        ServerAlias ideiassobrecodigo.com.br 

        <Directory /opt/company/ideiassobrecodigo>
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                RewriteEngine On
                Order deny,allow
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

obviously, each file had different names for each site.
In order to try to solve this problem I removed all files that configure the other sites and left only this one pointing directly to the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /opt/ideiassobrecodigo
        ServerName www.ideiassobrecodigo.com.br
        ServerAlias ideiassobrecodigo.com.br 

        <Directory /opt/ideiassobrecodigo>
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                RewriteEngine On
                Order deny,allow
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

when I did this I got a 403 forbidden error in the main page. Yet, if I put a random string in .htaccess in /opt/ideiassobrecodigo, I goes to error 500. So this time it's correctly pointing to the dir, yet I still got a 403 in the main page. So I changed to DocumentRoot back to /var/www/ideiassobrecodigo and it worked again. But the permalinks are broken again.

I rechecked the permissions, 755 to dirs, 644 to files as recommended. www-data:www-data is the owner of the folders and files.

Comment: Are you sure you're running v2.4.2 of WordPress?

Comment: Ups... 4.2.4. Edited. Sorry :D

Comment: run `apachectl -M` and check status of mod_rewrite.It will be helpful if you can put virtual host configuration here.

Comment: @WisdmLabs please see if the configurations I included in post suffice. Inform if you need any extra info  :)

Comment: If it were you, then instead of doing an edit as anonymous user, use your user account - thanks.

Comment: I edited from my tablet and the top screen wasn't visible. Aproved the Edition already.

Comment: That's a server 404, WordPress is not receiving those requests and isn't involved in the problem. `mod_rewrite` isn't working or your .htaccess file is being ignored.

Comment: Well I'm pretty confident mod_rewrite is enabled. Because (as stated above) apachectl -M list mod_rewrite. As to the option of WP not receiving these requests, how can I check it ? What could cause this if the blog is working fine in every other option and with permalinks default option. How can I check is my .htaccess is being ignored ? I have RewriteEngine On on my site configuration. Do I need anything else ?

Comment: The rewrite rules that WordPress inserts in .htaccess are to direct any request that is not for an existing physical file or directory to WordPress' index.php. If you then get a 404 for a request and the server's 404 page is displayed rather than WordPress' 404 page, then that means rewriting is not working. If the module is installed, it is then likely that the .htaccess file is not being parsed. You can confirm this by typing a random string in the file and saving it. If that does not trigger a 500 internal server error on any http request, then it's not being read.

Comment: @Nelson Teixeira, Thanks for providing the information. From this information, we can conclude that rewrite module is enabled. By virtualhost configuration, I meant content of the configuration file of your domain which is usually placed in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ directory. Thanks. :)

Comment: @WisdmLabs included the info you asked in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Apache server doesn't allow VHosts pointing to outside /var/www.
So I changed all (Document root AND Directory) to /var/www/site and it worked on all sites, with permalinks working fine.